# Chrome on Windows 7 is not respecting ClearType

Tags: windows-7, google-chrome, cleartype

I've noticed that my fonts seemed jagged on Chrome, but not Firefox, it seemed strange so I decided to configure ClearType again. It was already turned on, but I re-ran the config anyway.  What I've noticed is that if I turn ClearType on and off font on my desktop and in other applications will adjust, but Chrome continues to look the same.

Googling has shown that while FF and IE will force ClearType, Chrome is supposed to follow the Windows settings. I'm using Chrome 20(always updated) and Windows 7 64bit, why isn't chrome using ClearType?

Comment: This is a [known bug](https://www.google.com/search?q=chrome+cleartype). It is [*supposed* to be fixed](http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=96393), but there are still people for whom [it is not](http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=2387&). Try disabling the compositing and GPU acceleration functions (`chrome://flags`) then restart Chrome to see if it still happens.

Comment: Thanks I'll give it a try as soon as I get to my Windows machine.

Comment: Unfortunately they were both disabled already, I tried enabling and disabling which did not help. Thanks for your suggestion.

Comment: Try also updating video card and disabling "Accelerated 2D canvas" is in 'chrome://flags/' from: https://coderwall.com/p/9tecwq/fix-poor-font-rendering-in-chrome-on-windows